# How do I format subfigures captions using memoir?

Tags: floats, captions, memoir, subfloats

I switched to using the `memoir` class and stopped including subfigures. All of my subfigures now interpret the caption as actual text, i.e. as `[caption...]`, which shows up in the document with the square brackets. How do I created captioned subfigures using memoir?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
\newsubfloat{<float>}
```

to activate

```
\subbottom
\subtop
```

inside  environments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I know how to use it.  It says 'no counter "<float>" defined'

Comment: `\newsubfloat{figure}` if you want to use \subtop or \subbottom inside a `figure` environment. `\newsubfloat{table}` for tables.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Marin's answer, if you also want to use `cleveref` with `memoir`, I have found sub figures can not be properly referenced unless loading `subfig`. Here is what I do:

```
\RequirePackage[caption=false,position=top]{subfig}
\let\subtop\subfloat
```

so that I can continue using `\subtop` and if one day I decide to drop subfig my document needs no change.

A full example can look like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \subtop[1 pass]{\includegraphics{eye1}}%
  \subtop[5 passes]{\includegraphics{eye5}}%
  \caption{loop performance comparison}
  \label{fig:eye-comparison}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: how do you add captions?

Comment: For sub captions: `\subtop[caption]{\includegraphics{fig1}}`

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to include subfig though: ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@classoptionslist 
l.297 \ProcessPackageOptions

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I get this weird warning:

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{subfigure.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored


Any ideas?

Comment: Is this TeX FAQ useful http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=hyperdupdest?

Comment: I'll ask again here, but thanks.