# memoir class with subcaption and hyperref packages

Tags: hyperref, memoir, subfloats, incompatibility, subcaption

This is similar to this question about [using subfigures in memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/subfigures-with-memoir) and this one about [using subfigure memoir and hyperref together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/is-it-possible-to-use-hyperref-subfigure-and-memoir-together)

Is it possible to use memoir class with sucaption package?
I tried dissemulating the `ccaption` packages but it doesn't work.

`\DisemulatePackage{ccaption}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error

> LaTeX Error: Command \subcaption already defined.
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \subfloat already defined.

any ideas?

### Update

This doesn't work with `hyperref`... Adding 
 \usepackage{hyperref}
leads to compilation errors.

So the new question is, is it possible to use memoir class with sucaption and hyperref packages? Are the 3 packages compatible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately the combination of `memoir`, `caption`, and `hyperref` is not fully compatible. *(Not true anymore, see Addendum 2011-10-12.)*

When the memoir document class detects the caption package it will re-define some macros to full-feed the needs of the caption package; so this combination works fine alone. But when you load the hyperref package, the memoir class loads the memhfixc package additionally which redefines `\caption` which makes the caption package to enter the fall-back or so called "compatibility mode".

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption,hyperref}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

causes

```
Package caption Info: Incompatible package detected (regarding \caption).
(caption)             \caption = \long macro:->\donemaincaptiontrue \m@moldhypcaption .

Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

The subcaption package does not work well in "compatibility mode", causing it to behave strange. (The very next version will issue an error message instead.)

My proposal:

1. I will add the redefinition of the memhfixc package to the database of my caption package. This will stop the caption package from operating in compatibility mode.
2. I will ask the current maintainer of the memoir document class if any further adoption is necessary.

So hopefully this issue will be fixed very soon.

P.S.: Sorry for the late answer

### Addendum 2011-10-12

A new version of the caption package bundle is finally available on CTAN and as TeXlive update which fixes the hyperref compatibility issue. But one still needs

```
\let\subcaption\undefined
\let\subfloat\undefined
```

before loading the subcaption package since the memoir document class is not adapted to the subcaption package (yet).

### Addendum 2012-04-10

Finally I have found some time to take a closer look at this issue, and it seems that I was able to adapt the `subcaption` package for usage with the `memoir` document class. I'll release it with the upcoming version 3.3 of the `caption` package.

Comment: The issue is finally fixed, at least on the (sub)caption package side. See Addendum 2011-10-12 I just added to my answer.

Comment: Let me know if there is anything from the memoir side we can do to make caption vs. memoir easier. Eventhough I maintain memoir, I use caption a lot more than I use the memoir interface for captions.

Comment: @daleif: I'll write you an e-mail about that...

Comment: @Axel, I currently see only caption v3.2f on CTAN.  Is that v3.3 release expected soon?  I don't mean to be pushy, but this is something I'm definitely eager to use.  Thank you for any news you can offer!

Comment: Version 3.3 of the `caption` package was finally released in January. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
\let\subcaption\relax
\let\subfloat\relax
```

before loading those packages

(untested)

as for the hyperref try this (I do not garantee for other problems)

```
\let\captioncaption\caption
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\caption\captioncaption
```

Comment: @ daleif it works but only when "hyperref" is missing. Any more ideas? thank you

Comment: @pmav99: Take a look at my (new) answer