# subcaption package incompatible with memoir class?

Tags: memoir, subfloats, subcaption

When I try to compile a document with the `memoir` class and the subcaption package I get the following error:

> ! Package `subcaption` Error: This package can't be used in
>   cooperation with the `subfig` package.

I presume this is because the `memoir` class loads the `subfig` package. Is that correct?

Is there a way to make them work together?

Comment: Beyond what Harish says below, memoir also has built-in support for subfloats in general. See section 10.9 (Subcaptions) of the [memoir manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) -- no extra packages required, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `subfig` and `subcaption` packages can not be used in cooperation with each other. Instead, you can use`caption` package with `subfig` to add some flavor to the captions and subcaptions (or you can use `caption` along with `subcaption` (which gives a subfigure command also).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove [demo] in your file
\usepackage{subfig} % for subfigures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={it,small}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont={bf,small},textfont={it,small},
subrefformat=parens} %<-----designing subcaption
\newcommand{\myfigref}[2]{~\ref{#1}.\subref{#2}}% <---- a new macro for referring to a subfigure
%    
\begin{document}
%=========================
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
%=========================
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{my figure}
  \caption{My single picture}\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}
%=========================
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[My first picture]{\label{fig:mdleft}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{my figure}}}\hfill
\subfloat[My second picture]{\label{fig:mdright}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{my figure}}}
\caption{My two big pictures}
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
%===========================
From figure~\ref{fig:subfigures}.\subref{fig:mdleft}, we can see a small cat, in     
\myfigref{fig:subfigures}{fig:mdright} both can be used to refer figures.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would you modify the example above to be able to  `"subref"` to the subfigure captions? For example, in the text, I would like to say: `In Figure 2.(a) we show ... `. Also, why is it that your Figures start with the numbers `0.1` and `0.2`? How would make that to go with the numbers 1, 2 etc.?

Comment: @roseck See my edited answer.

Answer (score 11):

As Mike Renfro said in his comment, `memoir` already includes support for subfigures and subcaptions and there is no need to load packages `subfig` and `caption`. With next code you will reproduce Harish's result.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove [demo] in your file

\usepackage{lipsum}

% You need a newsubfloat element to use subcaption
\newsubfloat{figure}

% Command to set caption styles
\captionnamefont{\bfseries\small}
\captiontitlefont{\itshape\small}
\subcaptionlabelfont{\bfseries\small}
\subcaptionfont{\itshape\small}

%    
\begin{document}
%=========================
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
%=========================
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{my figure}
  \caption{My single picture}\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}
%=========================
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subbottom[My first picture\label{fig:mdleft}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{my figure}}\hfill
\subbottom[My second picture\label{fig:mdright}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{my figure}}
\caption{My two big pictures}
\label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}
%===========================

%In next paragraph look at differences between \ref{subfigurelabel},
%\subcaptionref{subfigurelabel} and \subcaptionref*{subfigurelabel}
%
In figure~\ref{fig:subfigures} we can see a small cat
(\ref{fig:mdleft} or \subcaptionref*{fig:mdleft}) and 
something else in \ref{fig:mdright} or \subcaptionref{fig:mdright}.    
\end{document}
```

`\newsubloat{figure}` declares a new subfloat element which allows to use `\subbottom` commands. Now `\ref{subfigurelabel}` equals to '1.2(a)' while `\subcaptionref{subfigurelabel}` equals to '(a)' (with font attibutes) and the [undocumented](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/comp.text.tex/subcaptionref/comp.text.tex/ymO21sVClfk/zLzxOwTwmCsJ) `\subcaptionref*` resets sublabel to normal font.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the error message is misleading (*), and the `memoir` document class is not working with my `subcaption` package yet.

But you can give

```
\let\subcaption\relax
\let\subfloat\relax
```

a try, just place this code before loading the `subcaption` package.

See also: [memoir class with subcaption and hyperref packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18931/memoir-class-with-subcaption-and-hyperref-packages)

(*) I have just changed that, so with future versions one will get the error message "Incompatible document class or package detected" instead.

Comment: I hope to be working on `memoir` soon again. Drop me an email, then er can see what can be done from the `memoir` side of things.

Comment: Finally I have found some time to take a closer look at this issue, and it seems that I was able to adapt the `subcaption` package for usage with the `memoir` document class. I'll release it with the upcoming version 3.3 of the `caption` package within the next weeks.

Comment: Thanks Axel for your work. Anyway I would like to let you know that while trying to compile memoir+subcaption with MacTex 2012 I still get the error from subcaption.

Comment: Unfortunately the new version of the caption package bundle is not ready yet :-( See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27437/2574