# Double brackets around captions when of subfigures

Tags: formatting, numbering, memoir, subfloats, subcaption

I am using subfigure to arrange 3by2 subfigures with captions each of them. Normally, the captions should look like this: (a) , (b). But instead they look like this: ((a)) , ((b)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Enable subfigures
\newsubfloat{figure}

% Section numbering depth
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}

% Make floats name bold
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}

\captionstyle{\OnehalfSpacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[t!] % "[t!]" placement specifier just for this example
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{pss_off_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{???? Power} \label{fig:pss_off_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{pss_off_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{????? Line Flow} \label{fig:pss_off_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab2_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{?????? Power} \label{fig:stab2_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab2_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{???? Line Flow 4041-4061} \label{fig:stab2_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab1_2_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{???????? Power} \label{fig:stab1_2_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab1_2_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{???????? Line Flow} \label{fig:stab1_2_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption{Comparison} \label{fig:pss_comparison}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of what you have now, could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current setup. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and not contain any unnecessary information; only stuff pertinent to replicate the current problem. That is, no need for `mathtools`, or `enumitem`, or `<whatever>`, as that doesn't play a part with sub-figures.

Comment: the class does warn you that you are straying out of supported territory `Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class.` memoir has its own mechanisms for caption formatting and if possible it's best to use those. (I don't really know memoir that well to give details)

Comment: see this for a memoir/subcaption setup that appears to work looking at the answer  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/subcaption-package-incompatible-with-memoir-class

Comment: For reference, none of the document class options are needed for this to be a minimal example. Neither are the ToC-related numbering reference, nor all the `\label`s. Finally, showing only two subfigures would suffice since it would highlight the problem equally well than displaying six subfigures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `subcaption` with `memoir` there is no need to say `\newsubfloat{figure}`. Remove that line and it's seems to be fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Enable subfigures
%\newsubfloat{figure} %commented

% Section numbering depth
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}

% Make floats name bold
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}

\captionstyle{\OnehalfSpacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[t!] % "[t!]" placement specifier just for this example
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{pss_off_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{???? Power} \label{fig:pss_off_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{pss_off_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{????? Line Flow} \label{fig:pss_off_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab2_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{?????? Power} \label{fig:stab2_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab2_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{???? Line Flow 4041-4061} \label{fig:stab2_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab1_2_powr4072.eps}
            \subcaption{???????? Power} \label{fig:stab1_2_p4072}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=15 3 32 20,clip,width=\linewidth]{stab1_2_powr40414061.eps}
            \subcaption{???????? Line Flow} \label{fig:stab1_2_pflow}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption{Comparison} \label{fig:pss_comparison}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) with [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) as it provides its own mechanism for setting sub-floats:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Enable subfigures
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \hfill
  \subbottom[First subcaption]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
  \hfill
  \subbottom[Second subcaption]{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}}
  \hfill\mbox{}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can change the formatting as well to suit your needs. See Chapter **10 Floats and captions** of the [`memoir` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).