# Pkg 'labbook' incompatible with pkg 'subcaption'?

Tags: memoir, koma-script, incompatibility, scrbook, labbook

**Disclaimer:** I know this is a question drawing opinionated answers. I still want to ask it, as I don't know how else I should proceed and am looking for advice.

I use [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) to write - you guessed it - a labbook. When I activate [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) in the preamble, all is fine, but as soon as I add [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), XeLaTeX throws:

> Command \theHsubfigure already defined.

To be honest, I load [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) by default, since I use them in most of my documents and I am pretty sure I will need them in my labbook, but I haven't included any images in my document, yet. The [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) class hasn't been updated since 2003 and the maintainer seems to have been active on ctan no later than 2007, when he last updated [`alnumsec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/alnumsec). The probability of [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) experiencing an update in the future is thus marginal at best. My uncoziness about this class arose when I got the error, even though my document is still pretty virgin (it's got 40 lines of code total, as of now). My question is therefore:

**What class do you recommend I use instead of [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) to write my labbook?**

I am - relatably, I think - not really keen on going on with an unmaintained document class to later hit some wall of unconceivable incompatibility with some important (otherwise well working) package and then have to rewrite all the structural parts of my TEX file.

I am just reading the [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook) documentation again and it says

> `labbook.cls` is based on the KOMA-Script-class `scrbook.cls`.

could this be the source of the incompatibility with [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)? I don't know KOMA-script very well. In [What packages are incompatible with KOMA-Script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73248/what-packages-are-incompatible-with-koma-script), [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) doesn't appear.

Furthermore, [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) used to be [incompatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48837) with [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), but [isn't any more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/subcaption-package-incompatible-with-memoir-class#comment106464_48864). I don't know if [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is based on [`scrbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrbook), but that doesn't really matter now, as it got updated to work with [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). Should I maybe use [`memoir`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) instead of [`labbook`](https://ctan.org/pkg/labbook)?

Comment: `memoir` and `scrbook` are NOT related. They were developed independently.

Comment: @PeterWilson that's correct, they are not. By reading a bit more about it, this became clear.

Comment: In case you read German you might be interested in https://komascript.de/node/2166. In particular Markus Kohm mentions that it is `labbook.sty` itself defines the problematic `\theHsubfigure` messing up `subcaption`. You may use any document class you like for you lab journal, it just depends on what you want and need. I would probably start with `scrreprt`/`scrbook` or `memoir` and write a few macros.

Comment: @moewe thx, I'll read this. I'll probably change the doc format, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained by moewe in a comment and by the KOMA-Script author [in German on komascript.de](https://komascript.de/node/2166) the problem is not KOMA-Script but `labbook`. To use `labbook` with `hyperref` you have to load it with option `hyperref`. But if you load it with option `hyperref` it does a

```
\newcommand*\theHsubfigure{%
  \theHfigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
```

just after loading `hyperref`. This does result in an error, because `subcaption` already defines `\theHsubfigure`. The only thing, you could do, is to *undefine* `\theHsubfigure` before loading `hyperref`. To do so, you can either use:

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{labbook}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\let\theHsubfigure\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[hyperref]{labbook}
\BeforePackage{hyperref}{\let\theHsubfigure\relax}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

However, you should note, `labbook` is unmaintained for several years and their is not warranty that such a hack really solves at least the issue from your question. [The `subcaption` author has some very clear words about `labbook`'s redefinition of `\theHfigure` and `\theHtable`](https://komascript.de/comment/5783#comment-5783) and IMHO the definition of `\theHsubfigure` is very similar to that. So if their wouldn't be a new maintainer that fixes all issues of `labbook` my recommendation would be the same as in moewe's comment below the question: *I would probably start with `scrreprt`/`scrbook` or `memoir` and write a few macros.* But I would not use `labbook` and at least not in combination with `subcaption`.

Comment: I ended up using doc-class memoir and dirty-hacking my way through it to get to an acceptable result that suits my needs more or less. Danke für die ausführlichere Antwort.