# What's next?—Moving away from labbook as my laboratory notebook

Tags: labbook

I learned today that using `labbook` is probably not a good idea because it is problematic and has not been maintained in many years. This makes me sad because I've been using it for 6+ years.

I'd like to move to something that is being maintained, but I'm afraid of how much effort is going to be required to get back to where I was.

Can someone provide some alternatives and how I can get there? Perhaps I just need to "roll my own".

Comment: where did you learn this? the class isn't very long or complicated 600 lines compared to 14174 of beamer for example. If for any reason it needed an update because of a change elsewhere in the tex world, someone would no doubt fix it.

Comment: I was trying to find out an issue that I had and ended up here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484961/6324

Comment: well I know nothing of labbook really but as  I say it's a pretty small class and the part that Markus (probably correctly) is complaining about is only a dozen lines. So if there is a good alternative to hand switch but if not, I wouldn't worry about it, if it stops working someone would always be able to fix it with only at most minor changes to the document.

Comment: It has stopped working for me now that I've switched to the `subcaption` package from the `subfig` package. I don't feel like my LaTeX chops are good enough to write/maintain a package. Perhaps this where I could learn and contribute at the same time.

Comment: if it has stopped then rather than asking an open ended "what other packages exist" question I would make a small test case that generates an error and ask about that.