# Set caption font size in memoir

Tags: captions, memoir, fontsize

How do I set the default caption font in a memoir?

I tried:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

But that gives me a warning:

> Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the
>   memoir (memoir) class. This may cause unexpected or inconsistent
>   (memoir) results if you use any of memoir's captioning facilities.

Comment: You should use the methods explained in section 10.6 of `memoir`'s manual (p. 193): `\captionnamefont{\small}\captiontitlefont{\small}` should do.

Comment: The warning just refers to the fact that if you load the `caption` package, then `memoir`s own caption configuration macros will no longer have any effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As egreg mentioned in his comment, you should use `memoir`'s commands `\captionnamefont` and `\captiontitlefont`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\captionnamefont{\small}
\captiontitlefont{\small}

\begin{document}
Test text

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
A
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! So I need to change both. I found the commands in the manual, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: I use `memoir` together with the `subcaption` package and the memoir commands `\captionnamefont` and `\captiontitlefont` have no effect. Instead it seems necessary to use `\captionsetup` to change the caption appearance. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do not use caption/subcaption package with memoir, they seem to be equivalent/conflicting. See: [memoir class with subcaption and hyperref packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18931/memoir-class-with-subcaption-and-hyperref-packages)